# compare 2 arrays so that if one array has elements within the other array these elements are eliminated from the other array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Using jquery or javascript how do I compare 2 arrays so that if one array has elements within the other array these elements are eliminated from the other array?

Comment: please specificate the question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must cross the two array and compare each element of the first with each element of the second, then, use the `Array.splice` method to remove an element.

```
for (var i in array1) {
    for (var j in array2) {
        if (array2[j] == array1[i]) {
            array2.splice(j, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```